# How to delete an element from a list while iterating over it in Python?

Tags: python

Given a list of numbers:

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

How do I delete an element, let's say 3, from the list while I iterate over it?

I tried the following code but it didn't do it:

```
for el in L:
    if el == 3:
        del el
```

Comment: This asking is not very good or generic, because it only asks about removing the first element matching a specific value, for which Python already has `L.remove(3)` builtin, or list comprehensions. But this asking won't cover all the more general cases like *"Remove duplicate adjacent values in a sorted list"*.

Comment: It's not clear what OP wanted in this question. Depending on the intent, either of the linked duplicates would be appropriate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Best is usually to proceed constructively -- build the new list of the items you want instead of removing those you don't.  E.g.:

```
L[:] = [el for el in L if el != 3]
```

the list comprehension builds the desired list and the assignment to the "whole-list slice", `L[:]`, ensure you're **not** just rebinding a name, but fully replacing the *contents*, so the effects are identically equal to the "removals" you wanted to perform.  This is also fast.

If you absolutely, at any cost, *must* do deletions instead, a subtle approach might work:

```
>>> ndel = 0
>>> for i, el in enumerate(list(L)):
...    if el==3:
...      del L[i-ndel]
...      ndel += 1
```

nowhere as elegant, clean, simple, or well-performing as the listcomp approach, but it does do the job (though its correctness is not obvious at first glance and in fact I had it wrong before an edit!-).  "at any cost" applies here;-).

Looping on indices in lieu of items is another inferior but workable approach for the "must do deletions" case -- but remember to *reverse* the indices in this case...:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(L))):
  if L[i] == 3: del L[i]
```

indeed this was a primary use case for `reversed` back when we were debating on whether to add that built-in -- `reversed(range(...` isn't trivial to obtain without `reversed`, and looping on the list in reversed order is sometimes useful.  The alternative

```
for i in range(len(L) - 1, -1, -1):
```

is really easy to get wrong;-).

Still, the listcomp I recommended at the start of this answer looks better and better as alternatives are examined, doesn't it?-).

Comment: Good idea. I didn't think of it. Thank you, Alex! :)

Comment: The second approach will delete the wrong elements when there's more than one element to delete, because the indices change after the first deletion.

Comment: @interjay, +1: you're right, I edited to compensate for that (unfortunately `reversed(enumerate(...` doesn't work -- `enumerate` is an iterable but not a sequence, `reversed` needs a sequence as its argument).

Answer (score -4):

```
for el in L:
    if el == 2:
        del L[el]
```

Comment: need to enumerate so that you can index L[idx].

Comment: Nope, this will behave in really weird ways indeed -- removing L's "third item" (possibly more than once) if completely unrelated items equal `2`, and often skipping an item in L when it does such removals. What a nightmare to debug...!-)