# Why strange list comprehension behavior with side effects?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension, side-effects

I know that using side effects in Python list comprehensions is not good practice. But I can't understand why something like the following happens:

```
In [66]: tmp = [1,2,3,4,5]; [tmp.remove(elem) for elem in tmp]
Out[66]: [None, None, None]

In [67]: tmp
Out[67]: [2, 4]
```

Whether or not this is good practice, shouldn't the interior of the list comprehension do something predictable? If the above *is* predictable, can someone explain why only three `remove` operations occurred, and why the even entries are the ones that remain?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442651/how-to-delete-an-element-from-a-list-while-iterating-it-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @JoshLee I don't need to delete the elements, per se, I just wanted to understand why the `None or...` stuff wasn't working. It turns out it was working and I didn't realize the index was changing.

Comment: Also, in the example this derives from, the part where I am putting `None` is actually an expensive computation that may result in returning `None`, in which case deleting the items from `tmp` where that occurs *may* be a viable choice for me. But either way, it won't be good to also include an `if` clause at the end of the list comprehension because it would require evaluating that expensive function again to know what to keep.

Comment: Well, you can always rewrite `None or x` as simply `x`.

Comment: `None` may be returned by an expensive function in my actual code.

Comment: Of course. But to distill this example down to its essence, it could help to realize that every `None` in your result is actually the return value from `tmp.remove`.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll edit. But I think this is still different from the linked question in which a simple conditional in the comprehension solves the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't about listcomps, it's about removing from lists you're iterating over:

```
>>> tmp = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for elem in tmp:
...     tmp.remove(elem)
... 
>>> tmp
[2, 4]
```

It goes something like this:

```
>>> tmp = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> for elem in tmp:
...     print elem, tmp
...     tmp.remove(elem)
...     print elem, tmp
... 
1 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
1 [2, 3, 4, 5]
3 [2, 3, 4, 5]
3 [2, 4, 5]
5 [2, 4, 5]
5 [2, 4]
```

First it's looking at the 0th element, and 1 is removed.  So on the next iteration, it wants to remove the 1st element, which is now the 3, etc.

Comment: Gotcha, so if I make it `[None or tmp.remove(elem) for elem in list(tmp)]` or `[None or tmp.remove(elem) for elem in tmp[:]]` then it should work "as expected" (still being bad style and all).

Answer (score -1):

It's never a good idea to remove from a list as you're iterating over it directly.
Edit: whoops, I was confusing lists with dictionaries. Dictionaries have an iteritems() and iterkeys() method which is what you would use when you're iterating over a dictionary and removing items from it.

For a list, you would probably want to copy the list if you want to do this inside a list comp. Or, alternately:

```
[None and tmp.pop(0) for i in xrange(len(tmp))]
```